# Alignment of table content of different font-size

Tags: pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm filling a table with different size text (left column Helvetica 6pt, right column Times 8pt), but the baselines of the texts do not align - the left text is visibly higher than the one in the right column. How do I get it nice? Using **FOP 2.1**.

One way would be to add `line-height=...` but then what value would I have to set line-height to in order to get the same vertical spacing that I have now?

Isn't there a more generic way?

```
    <fo:block-container position="absolute" top="27mm" left="125mm" width="75mm" font-family="Times" font-size="8pt">
        <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
            <fo:table-column column-width="2.7cm"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="4cm"/>
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block margin-top="12pt" font-size="6pt" font-family="Helvetica">Contact:</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block margin-top="12pt">Normally me</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block font-size="6pt">&#xa0;</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>Manager</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block font-size="6pt" font-family="Helvetica">email:</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>dings@bums</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
    </fo:block-container>
```

Comment: XSL 1.1 defines, but FOP doesn't support, `relative-align` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#relative-align) specifically for aligning the first lines of content in table cells and aligning content in an `fo:list-item-label` with its `fo:list-item-body`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More research and a comment putting more light: `line-height="inherit"`

```
<fo:block font-size="6pt" font-family="Helvetica" line-height="inherit">
```

in all the blocks of the left column 
does it in this case without specifying an explicit line-size anywhere.

Comment: `line-size` isn't defined in XSL 1.1.

Comment: sure you are right! bad error of mine, I meant `line-height` , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking typographically and for the situation you're describing, if you want both columns to share the same baseline, your larger typeface, the 8-point Times Roman, should be the one to set your line spacing (or leading), not your smaller one.

8-point Times expects a default leading of 8 points from one baseline down to the next one. Any less than that and its descenders from an upper line risk crashing into ascenders on a lower line; thus you can't reduce its linespacing to match the 6-point Helvetica next door.

If the left text comes out higher than the right, it's presumably because the glyphs are positioned by dropping down to a baseline first, then placing the text. Thus the 6-point Helvetica drops 6 points before setting; the 8-point Times drops 8 points before setting, and you're looking at a misalignment. Determine which of your columns will have the largest leading value, set your other column(s) to match it by adding the appropriate amount of inter-line leading, and that should keep things in alignment with each other. (Your smaller faces are still going to look rather whitespacey, however; you might consider just boosting them to match the largest point size in that table row.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm actually doing that - the `line-size="inherit"` draws the height for the 8pt Times that is set in the containing `fo:block`. Though that might look different if you set the sizes individually in the columns and not by chance the bigger one outside that you can then easily inherit.

Comment: of course I meant `line-height`instead of line-size